# Jenkins returns null instead of error in output

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

There is my code

```
def build() {
      try {
// some build gradle task here 
// gradle  install task
}
catch(Throwable err) {
     //   println "DEBUGGGGGGG"

     globalVar.echo "TEST#"


        globalVar.echo "TEST#"
        globalVar.echo err.getMessage()
        globalVar.echo "TEST"
        globalVar.echo err.getCause()
        globalVar.echo "TESTSSSS"

        throw err 
     }
      finally {

}
```

jenkins  Output from my job:

> Pipeline] echo
>       TEST#
>       [Pipeline] echo
>       TEST#
>       [Pipeline] echo
>       null
>       [Pipeline] echo
>       TEST
>
> Finished: FAILURE [Pipeline] echo null [Pipeline] echo TESTSSSS

then trows Exception

> hudson.model.Run$RunnerAbortedException
>         at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.GradleExecutor.exe(GradleExecutor.java:144)
>         at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.common.executors.GradleExecutor.execute(GradleExecutor.java:69)
>         at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.ArtifactoryGradleBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryGradleBuild.java:89)
>         at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.scripted.steps.ArtifactoryGradleBuild$Execution.run(ArtifactoryGradleBuild.java:65)
>         at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
>         at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
>         at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

How can I get Exception cause ? in my case if i run gradle install  from command line ( without jenkins ) is :
 error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to boolean

but I would to see error in jenkins job console output

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
try{
//your code
}
catch (exc){
println exc
}
```

Works for me.